# Ping to router gives high latency at random

Tags: networking, router, ping

Using MultiPing I'm pinging to my router (192.168.0.1), but at random this gives high latency of >500ms or packet loss.

I have two other routers in my network (but configured as switches) which give steady low ping (192.168.0.2 and 192.168.0.3), but only my modem/router at 192.168.0.1 gives random ping peaks. At the same cable-end I tried MultiPing on my laptop, giving the same effect.

This causes stuttering in especially games. I bet the problem lies with the router (local problem), how can I solve this? Incidentally, loading admin pages from the router is slow as hell...

I have an Ubee router (from Ziggo, Netherlands) with serial no. EVW320B50410930

Comment: Try a different cable.  Try a replacement router.

Comment: I just tried another cable directly on the router, same thing. The router is 1 month old, so I think it's either some setup issue or ISP related.